# Why does audio in MediaPlayer not loop?

Tags: android, audio, android-emulator, android-mediaplayer

This is the portion of my code:

```
sound= MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),R.raw.sound);
sound.start();
sound.setLooping(true);
```

This doesn't loop the audio once it is completed. Then I checked some other solutions previously posted in this site and tried the following:

```
sound= MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),R.raw.sound);
sound.start();
sound.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.seekTo(0);
                        mp.start();
                    }
                });
```

This also didn't help restarting the audio after it finished once. 
Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was with my emulator (Genymotion) which was not looping. When I tried the apk in my actual android device, it  worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s just that you’re starting it, then trying set it to loop. Try it like this instead.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mp!=null){
                mp.reset();
                mp.release();
            }
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound);
            mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```